# Reindex child of a hierarchical index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a hierarchical index pandas dataframe. "sentence_id" is the parent-index of "word_id", where "word_id" means the index of word in a sentence.

```
>>> df
                     pos        word
sentence_id word_id                 
1           2        NNP         Red
            3         NN        List
            4         IN          of
            5        NNP  Threatened
            6        NNP     Species
```

In each sentence, the word_id are supposed to be consecutive integers 0,1,2,3,... But they are not, because some words were dropped from a sentence. How can I use df.reindex to re-index the child-index "word_id" in each sentence, without modifying the "sentence_id"? 
i.e. how can the dataframe above become:

```
>>> df
                     pos        word
sentence_id word_id                 
1           0        NNP         Red
            1         NN        List
            2         IN          of
            3        NNP  Threatened
            4        NNP     Species
```

What I tried:
I tried df.reindex(), but "word_id" didn't have any change

```
>>> df.reindex()
                     pos        word
sentence_id word_id                 
1           2        NNP         Red
            3         NN        List
            4         IN          of
            5        NNP  Threatened
            6        NNP     Species
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new column with count for each group of index level 0 and replace level1 of index

```
df = df.reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
df['word_id'] = df.groupby(level='sentence_id').cumcount()
df.set_index('word_id', append=True)

                     pos        word
sentence_id word_id                 
1           0        NNP         Red
            1         NN        List
            2         IN          of
            3        NNP  Threatened
            4        NNP     Species
```